# Why a thermoelectric generator's efficiency increases when the thermal conductivity of thermoelectric materials decreases?

Tags: peltier

A thermoelectric generator generates electricity from the flow of heat.The heat flow rate will increase if the thermal conductivity will increase. So the power generation should increase too. So why a thermoelectric generator's  efficiency increases when the thermal conductivity of thermoelectric materials decreases where the efficiency of the thermoelectric generator should be proportional to the thermal conductivity of thermoelectric materials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two components to the thermal  conductivity of a thermoelectric generator - one (the one that is meant here) is constant with load and represents the bulk of the heat flow. This behaves like a resistor - the higher the temperature difference the larger proportionally the heat flow, analogous to Ohm's law. The other (much smaller part) varies with the load and represents the useful part of the heat flow. It is zero with the  TEG open and maximum with it shorted. The maximum power output increases with heat flow (caused by temperature difference) but so does the wasted energy (in electrical terms like a low-value resistor in parallel with the input of a power supply).  Unfortunately high electrical conductivity generally goes together with high thermal conductivity and so the thermal losses increase if you try to reduce the electrical losses. TEGs are subject to the same Carnot limit of other heat engines as a theoretical maximum, but they don't even approach that generally.

Answer (score 2):

Thermoelectric generators (TEGs) convert heat energy to electrical energy. They rely on a temperature difference between the hot and cold junctions : that temperature difference creates a voltage difference between the two junctions, and it is that voltage difference that allows you to extract energy.

However the hot and cold junctions are connected by the TEG itself, which conducts heat energy from the hot to the cold junction. This conducted heat bypasses the energy conversion process and is a pure waste of energy. So the higher the thermal conductivity of your TEG, the more energy it wastes ... and so, the less efficient it is.